# Add Installer link error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-services, visual-studio-2017

I have error while attempt to [add installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/how-to-add-installers-to-your-service-application) to windows service.

[image]

```
The system cannot find the file specified (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)
```

Above error happens starting from second attempt to add installer. First time (after vs restart) I got next error message :

```
Cannot find the requested source : '300'
```

[image]

Have I missed something? Thanks.

Comment: Why does this question was downvoted? Any explanations? I see no obvious reason.

Comment: After adding net components to vs  installation problem was resolved

Comment: Which net components are needed to be add?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved adding the **.NET desktop development** module in the Visual Studio Installer and trying again:

[image: see image]